# Not getting updated merge quote id using customer_login observer

Tags: magento2, customer, login, quote, quoteitem

Using `customer_login`, not getting merge cart quote id . its provide new increment quote id. anyone know which one event use for get updated quote id after customer login.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below event work for me for getting new quote id after cart merge on customer login

```
customer_data_object_login
```